# SSO and OAuth Confusion

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, adfs, federation

This is actually a question about what I actually need instead of a howto.

We have a client that uses Ping Identity/Ping Federate to enter all of the sites in their system. We have developed a web application for them that they want to access to from their main portal instead of getting separate logins for our site.

They didn't tell us very much but they seemed to have the idea that we also needed to buy into Ping Identity/Federate or setup an ADFS farm so they could access our system.

This is where I'm confused. Wouldn't it be easier/make more sense just to have that link in their main portal (once they've authenticated with Ping) to call a REST API on our site that takes their user name(Email in this case) and a token and then logs them in? We are smaller company and I can't imagine it being worth it at all to setup an ADFS farm or get an expensive Ping license for this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can get started with Azure AD for free. Most of the functionality you likely want is free and it makes for a highly reliable and scalable security token service that can service your app without implementing AD FS, Ping or any other solution.

Comment: I was able to get SSO working in my dev environment using this great tutorial from http://www.primaryobjects.com/2013/08/08/using-single-sign-on-with-windows-identity-foundation-in-mvc-net/, but it does leave me with one last question. Our client is expecting an entity ID from us that was not covered in this tutorial. What what I have read, it basically would be a URL that points to a Controller that would generate/return a Shibboleth SAML assertion. Thoughts?

Comment: entityid is a URI that uniquely identifies your app. It doesn't have to be a URL. Assertion consumers are endpoints/URLs that consume incoming tokens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your customer is actually asking you to provide a federated authentication method leveraging an industry standard like SAML 2.0 or OpenID Connect*. I think this is reasonable because;

- They won't have to implement a one-off solution. I'd also push for using a standard (talking from experience).
- Selling the same solution to other customers would be easier as you'd have a standard solution.

This being said, there are many alternatives to setting up PingFederate or ADFS, which can be roughly viewed in three groups:

- IDaaS: Azure AD, PingOne, Okta, OneLogin etc. They take over the federation tasks and usually have very easy integration options for developers, either at reasonable prices or even free.
- On-Premise Federation Solutions: Like PingFederate and ADFS, but there are also open-source alternatives. They again take care of federation and provide easy integration options for developers.
- Federation Frameworks/Libraries: Just search for it in your preferred language, Spring Security is a good option for Java for instance. By using these your application would be federation-capable by itself. These are usually free but require integration into the application, which can be complicated at times.

*: Please don't use OAuth2 for authentication purposes, that's not what it's for.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Right now I'm actually working with a tutorial from http://www.primaryobjects.com/2013/08/08/using-single-sign-on-with-windows-identity-foundation-in-mvc-net/   I'm actually learning quite a bit and think I'll have a working solution this afternoon.